# Wordpress TIny editor and upload option conflict

Tags: jquery, wordpress, tinymce, media

I am using upload media option and Tiny editor in my theme option. Now when I am using below javascript

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.st_upload_button').click(function() {
         targetfield = jQuery(this).prev('.upload-url');
         tb_show('', 'media-upload.php?type=image&amp;TB_iframe=true');
         return false;
    });
    window.send_to_editor = function(html) {
         imgurl = jQuery('img',html).attr('src');
         jQuery(targetfield).val(imgurl);
         tb_remove();
    }
});
```

it is allowing to upload image and insert url from upload button (see image with input and black upload button)

[image]

but with above javascript Tiny editor allowing upload but stops to inserting image into the editor.

[image]

I cross checked by disabling javascript and than Tiny editor works fine. So I believe something wrong in javascript but can't understand what is wrong and how to solve.

Comment: do you get any js errors inyour console?

Comment: can you examine your code closer: write a console.log-statement between each line of code and tell us, which line is the last one that gets executed -> this way we can get to know which line causes trouble

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no problem in the jquery, only some has to be made while registering your scripts here is an sample code

```
     function st_add_init() 

    {

   $screen = get_current_screen();
   $file_dir = get_template_directory_uri();
   wp_enqueue_style("stCss", $file_dir."/font/theme-options.css", false, "1.0",    "all"); 
   wp_enqueue_script("stScript", $file_dir."/js/theme-options.js", false, "1.0");                             wp_register_script('my-upload', get_bloginfo( 'stylesheet_directory' ) .'/js/my-script.js', array('jquery','media-upload','thickbox'));    
   if ($screen->id =='appearance_page_st-settings')   
        {
          wp_enqueue_script('thickbox');
          wp_enqueue_script('media-upload');
          wp_enqueue_script('my-upload');
          wp_enqueue_style('thickbox');

        }
   }
   add_action('admin_enqueue_scripts', 'st_add_init');
```

The **get_current_screen();**  function retrieves the id of your theme option page

**'appearance_page_st-settings'** is the id of my option page, yours will be different

**if ($screen->id =='appearance_page_st-settings')** the id will be matched to identify whether the page is theme option page,if true, the script will be registered, therefore avoiding any conflict with the admin script